Small leak in the ceiling, open plumbing vent directly over it
I woke up this morning to a slow drip in my ceiling. I went up into the attic to investigate and discovered there is plumbing vent pipe right above the spot where the leak was. I ran my hand over the pipe and it was not wet. I then noticed that there is a tee connector, where one part of the pipe branches off and goes down the house, while the other end is open to the elements. I surmise that due to the heavy wind and rain we had last night, some water made it into the vent on the roof,  is the bottom of the vent pipe supposed to be exposed like that? I’ve attached a couple of photos to show what I’m seeing.



In the photos, you can see where I circled the bottom of the pipe with a red circle. There is no cap on that part of the pipe. It goes straight from the roof vent to 1/2 inch above the leak.

The length of the pipe is dry. The area where the pipe goes through the roof is dry. All of the insulation around the area is dry. The ceiling is dry except for the one tiny area where it leaked. Note: It is no longer dripping/leaking.

There is a “T” connector. The vent splits off, goes about 10 feet and then drops into the ceiling.

There is no cap. The vent is open. And it is too close to the ceiling to serve any purpose.

Got it. That’s what I thought. The house was built in 1984 and the venting looks original.

Thank you for your patience and explanation and expertise. I truly appreciate it.

I see no photos?

You have not, AFAICT, attached any photos.

The pipe going downwards from the tee does not connect to a plumbing stack, that pipe should not be there.
Vents are required to slope downwards to a drain, downwards facing stubs are not allowed. open vents inside the building are even worse.
Slit the hubs off the tee and break it off (some heat may help). Then glue in an elbow there.
If you can't get the tee off cleanly cut the ends square and use two 45 degree elbows instead.
That horizontal pipe needs to slope downwards, so you may need to adjust its height a bit. you may need to add pipe supports.

Apologies all. I thought the photos attached but they did not. Should be viewable now.

Vent piping is not required to have drainage slope above the flood level of the highest connected fixture, but should not have any sags or reverse slope anywhere, so water cannot collect. All piping has support requirements put forth in the plumbing codes.
